# Where is the implementation of cpython's list type?

Tags: python, list, cpython

I'd like to know where the `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`code of pythons list type is defined. I know the list is implemented in C, but I can't find the code implementing the indexing and slicing operations of lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find everything in the [`listobject.c` file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c).

It's methods are enumerated in the [`list_methods()` structure](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2358). You may also want to study the [`PyList_Type` structure](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2615) for further pointers to implementations of various hooks.

Since `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are part of both the [C sequence protocol](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#sequence-object-structures), the `PyList_Type` structure points to a new structure [`list_as_sequence`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2376) that defines those hooks, listed in the `tp_as_sequence` slot of `PyList_Type`.

The [`list_item` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l415) implements the `__getitem__` hook, and `__setitem__` is represented by [`list_ass_item`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l726).

Slices, on the other hand, are handled by the mapping protocol, and you'll end up (via [`list_as_mapping`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2609)) at [`list_subscript`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2394) and [`list_ass_subscript`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2447).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the file [`listobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cd07899baf/Objects/listobject.c) ... I added an [answer earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13048210/748858) which points to a lot of the things you're looking for